# how to add footer after background-img?

Tags: html, css, footer

I tried to add the footer, but it adds on top of the background-image at the bottom of my page.  I tried to remove the "display:fixed" from footer, but the horizontal scroll shows up. How can I fix this?

I want the footer to be always visible on the screen when you scroll the page.

Here is more detail code snipet, I would appreciate if you guys can help with this.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Google Sans',Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

body {
  background-image: url("/img/bg-new-edit.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh; 
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

/* Basic styling */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 350;
  margin: 580px 40px;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
}
}
```

```html
<body>

<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="logo"><a href="#"><img class="logo" src="img/TARRAHJEWELRY-LOGO.png"></a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li class="item has-submenu dropdown">
      <a tabindex="0">Bridal Jewelry</a>
      <ul class="submenu dropdown-content">
        <li class="subitem"><a href="engagement.html">Engagement</a></li>
        <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Men Wedding</a></li>
        <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Women Wedding</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item has-submenu dropdown">
      <a tabindex="0">Collection</a>
      <ul class="submenu dropdown-content">
        <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Ring</a></li>
        <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Necklace</a></li>
        <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Earring</a></li>
        <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Bracelet</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item"><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item button"><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
    <li class="item button"><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
    <li class="toggle"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

 <h2>We believe people who live life in their special way,<br> deserve unique jewelry.</h2>

<footer><p>Footer</p></footer>
 


<div class="clearfix"></div>

 </body>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific on the expected behavior of your footer positioning, should it be always visible on the screen when you scroll the page, or do you just want it to be bottom aligned if there is not enough content? Also, your snippet is not working, you need to add both HTML and CSS to the snippet and check that it works (press the RUN button in snippet editor, check that it looks like on your real site).

Comment: What is the background image applied to. If it to the `body` tag you may need to adjust your html. Consider a [MCVE]

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough details. I just edited the code snipet with html and css. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

select the footer

```
footer {
bottom: 0;
position: fixed
}
```

**note that this will cause a scroll bar to appear**
to remove the scroll bar

```
body {
overflow: hidden
 }
That should solve your problem
```

Comment: next time when asking questions, it's best to add your html code. It makes it easier for people to answer your questions

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just added html and more detail css.

Comment: no problem i have seen your code and i have updated my response.